# Swift delay after if is true

Tags: swift, if-statement, delay, sleep

I am currently learning Swift and can not continue. I create a dice game. If the "if query" is true, the program should pause briefly before a new query is possible.

```
@IBAction func guess(_ sender: Any) {
    let diceRoll = arc4random_uniform(5)
    let fingerErgebnis = diceRoll + 1
    let fingerAntwort = String(fingerErgebnis)

    if fingerTextfield.text == fingerAntwort{
        ergebnis.text = "Richtig erraten!"
        ergebnis.textColor = UIColor.green
        ergebnis.font = ergebnis.font.withSize(20)
        bild.image = UIImage(named: ("win.jpg"))
        button.setTitle("Neues Spiel!", for: .normal)
        fingerTextfield.text = " "
        sleep (2)



    }else if fingerErgebnis == 1 {
        ergebnis.text = "Leider falsch! Die Zahl war \(fingerAntwort)."
        ergebnis.textColor = UIColor.red
        bild.image = UIImage(named: ("finger1.jpg"))
        button.setTitle("Versuch es nochmal!", for: .normal)

    } ...
```

As far as everything works, but I want that everything is running first and I have to wait 2 seconds until I can click the button again. My test is paused first, then the rest of the if commands are executed. I want that the other way around.

Sorry for my terrible english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable your button and re-enable it after two seconds using `async(deadline:execute:)`. So, instead of `sleep(2)` put the following:

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
  // assuming button is a property of the current view controller
  self?.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works with


`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
                // assuming button is a property of the current view controller
                self?.button.isHidden = false
            }`

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    sleep (2)
> ```

This is the wrong way to create the delay you're looking for. `sleep()` stops your process entirely, at least on that thread. What you should do instead is to disable the button and then use a [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) (or some other form of delayed execution, but Timer is easy) to re-enable it two seconds later.